# Need to connect solr in cluster mode with authentication

Tags: solr, jetty, solr4

I have solr in cloud mode along with zookepers configuration.
find below the configuration

```
core ---------|--shard1 --|--server1:7250
              |           |--server2:7300
              |           |--server3:7250
              |
              |--shard2--|--server1:7050
                         |--server2:7300
                         |--server3:7250
```

to this setup I have to enable basic authentication. 
I did that by making the below changes in 
jetty.xml

```
    <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
         <Set name="name">Realm</Set>
         <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
         <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
       </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

webdefault.xml

```
 <!--security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>Disable TRACE</web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint/>
 </security-constraint-->
 <security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>Disable TRACE</web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
     <role-name>admin</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>

 <login-config>
   <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
   <realm-name>Realm</realm-name>
 </login-config>
```

and added a realm.properties file.

On doing this the basic auth got enabled but the jetty servers are not able to connect to each other Hence I am getting unauthorized error with not anle to connect /solr

I need to make sure that the jetty are able to communicate by exchanging auths. And authorization and authentication are provided at solr admin portal level.

Please help.

Comment: You should _really_ consider moving to the built-in [support for authentication in Solr through security.json](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html). Are you doing manual sharding, or are you using the built-in clustering support?

Comment: @MatsLindh I am using sharding,  we just pass sharding information at the time of core creatin
So I need this for providing authentication  at the admin portal level. Will zookeeper help in that case as well.